# Android: After changing action bar height, the navigation indicator(icon) not centered vertical

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I write an Android app with Navigation Drawer (use android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout and android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle)

This is the screenshot with the customized navigation indicator (icon), and it is centered vertical.
[image]

After I changed the action bar height, the navigation indicator (icon) is not centered vertical.
[image]

I change the action bar height in style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bar</item>
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/action_bar_height</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/action_bar_height</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bar</item>
    <item name="height">@dimen/action_bar_height</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/action_bar_height</item>
</style>
```

How can I put the navigation indicator (icon) to centered vertical.

**Edited:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard_logged_in);

    mContext = this;

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.layout_actionbar_login);

    initView();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 }


private void initView() {
    // DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = createDrawerToggle();
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    // ListView
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_item_layout, mDrawerList);
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}


private ActionBarDrawerToggle createDrawerToggle() {
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.light_menu_r, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);

            getDrawerToggleDelegate().setActionBarUpIndicator(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dark_menu_r), R.string.settings);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
            Log.d("Eric Eric", "hahaha");
            getDrawerToggleDelegate().setActionBarUpIndicator(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_menu_r), R.string.coupon_list);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
        }
    };

    return drawerToggle;
}
```

Thanks.
Eric

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution for this? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your app theme is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" and you widget theme is "Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse" That is the reason why this misalignment is happening.

Comment: No, it's absolutely not

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but I ran into this problem recently. After hours of trying to figure if this was a problem of the toolbar, the actionbar, the actionbardrawertoggle or the indicator drawable itself, it turned out the solution was extremely simple.

You only need to specify a minimum height in the toolbar as stated in Google's developer console. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

Solution:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
android:minHeight="@dimen/toolbar_height" ... />
```